# How to efficiently filter objects out of an (initially) large list of objects

Tags: c#, performance, linq, list, large-data-volumes

I need to filter a large list of complex (20+ properties) objects into multiple sub lists. To create the sub-lists, I have a list of filter specifications.   Requirements are: a) An item is not allowed to be part of two sub lists and b) it must be possible to get hold of all undivided items after processing has finished.

Currently I use the following algorithm:

1. List item
2. Put the objects to be filtered in a Generic List
3. For each filter specification:

   - Create a Where expression (Expression>)
   - Apply the expression using Linq > Where to the list of objects
   - Get the resulting IEnumerable of selected objects and store them in a list, together with the description of the filter
   - Remove the items found from the source list using Linq > Except to create a new list to continue working with and to prevent an object from being put in more than one sub list
4. Check whether there a still (undivided) objects in the working list

My initial list of objects can be over 400.000 objects and I've noticed that both the filtering, as well as reducing the working list takes some time. So I would like to know:

1. Filtering to create the sub-lists takes place on a maximum of 7 properties of my object. Is there a way to improve performance of a Linq > Where selection?
2. Is there a way to prevent items from being selected into multiple sub-lists, without reducing the working collection by using Except or RemoveAll (possible improvement)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It all depends if the list of objects is ordered or indexed in anyway by some of the filtering properties. If its not, it will probably be *much* faster to just iterate manually (`foreach`) only once through the list and classify the items in sequence with an `if elseif else` statement.

Comment: How can you create an index on a collection of objects that can be used by Linq? Further more, the real-life situation is more complex than my description above. In real-life, there is not just a list of filter descriptions, but there is a tree-structure of categories with every category having its own filter specification and (eventually) sub-list of objects that comply with the filter specification.

Comment: Well that's my point. If the list is not indexed in any way then using *Linq*'s `Where` extension method is basically going to iterate the whole sequence anyway. In that case you are better off iterating *only once* and classifying each item as you go avoiding costly *remove* and *except* operations alltogether

Comment: Classyfying them will be a challenge, because the filters do not only contain tests for equality, but also greater than, less than etc. and the property values are not limited to let's say two or three values, theoretically resulting in more unique combinations than the number of objects I have to filter.

Comment: Why classifying would be a problem? Linq `Where` is nothing more that iterating and evaluating the predicate. Can't you build a list of predicate/output list pairs?

Comment: I'm not understanding you. You have an algorithm in place that works but you want to improve performance. If it works, then you have a way of building all the predicates in your `Where` clauses. What is preventing you of doing it manually? See my answer below. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: I think I misunderstood 'classifying' as a result of English not being my primary language... ;) The example clarifies everything though!

Comment: I have created custom Expression tree code of type `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`, for all kinds of complex filters, for types `String , Int, long, DateTime, bool, decimal`, applied in any permutation. In fact for large set with millions of records, as I use TPL for subsets, it is very fast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can not leverage any indexes in the incoming list you are trying to classify then you are better off just iterating through the whole list *only once* and classifying the items as you go. This way you avoid unnecessary *remove* and *except* operations that are seriously hurting the performance with pointless iterations and equality comparisons.

I was thinking about something a long the lines of:

```
public static IDictionary<string, List<T>> Classify<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IDictionary<string, Predicate<T>> predicates, out List<T> defaultBucket)
{
    var classifiedItems = new Dictionary<string, List<T>>(predicates.Count);
    defaultBucket = new List<T>();

    foreach (var predicate in predicates)
    {
        classifiedItems.Add(predicate.Key, new List<T>()); 
    }

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var matched = false;

        foreach (var predicate in predicates)
        {
            if (predicate.Value(item))
            {
                matched = true;
                classifiedItems[predicate.Key].Add(item);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!matched)
        {
            defaultBucket.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return classifiedItems;
}
```

Any given `predicate` can be as complex as you need it to be. Only condition is that it takes in a `T` and returns a `bool`. If that is not enough, nothing is preventing you from implementing your own `MyPredicate<???>` with whatever signature you need.

*EDIT*: Edited the code to handle a "*default bucket*" where  items that don't comply with any of the specified predicates go.

Comment: I think exactly the same. A typical partition algorithm. +1

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. This really is the type of answer that I'm looking for. Of course I can traverse my tree of categories.at first to collect all the predicates. I think there should be one addition to the example above and that is to make a collection of items that do not apply to any of the predicates.

Comment: Yup, I didn't account for any items that didn't meet any of the specified conditions. Still, that is pretty trivial to solve.

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart Added how I'd handle the "default bucket" case.

Comment: You add to `defaultBucket` after each failed predicate, not when all predicates failed.

Comment: @PetSerAl Woops! True, fixed that. Thanks!